# Maximal Utility Principle

Tags: probability, utility

There are 2 possible scenarios, A and B. Scenario A has a 50% chance of being successful. Scenario B has two stages and a 80% chance of being successful at the first stage. If Scenario B is successful at the first stage (B.1), then there is a 100% chance of being successful at B.2.1 and a 50% chance of being successful at B.2.2 (B.2.1 and B.2.1 are not mutually exclusive).

Which scenario should we pick? I am having trouble finding the solution and determining the utilities.

Comment: When you say not mutually exclusive, how do we know if each of B.2.1 and B.2.2 will happen? It's not clear to me from the wording. From what I see now though, it seems like you would want to pick A, because the chance of being successful is 50%. For B, passing the first stage already is only a 20% chance and you're only making it more conditional with the extra stages.

Comment: I think both will happen. The problem is that I myself was not sure by reading the question what would happen. I see what you mean about the 20%. I will change is to 80% to make my point better. If B has a 80% success rate, then how would you proceed?

Comment: If both happen, consider that B has 80% chance of passing at stage 1, and at stage 2 it has to pass B.2.1 and B.2.2, the chance of passing is hard to determine with the way the question is phrased. If they are independent events, you can just do 100% * 50% = 50%, but if they are not independent we would need more information to determine the answer. We would also have to consider whether B.1 and B.2 (B.2.1 and B.2.2) are independent, before we can simply do 80% * 50% = 40%. If you have the original problem with its wordings it might be easier to help.

Comment: How would we determine Utilities? Basically it is a question about digital forensics and the original wording said that A=Post-mortem Forensics and B=Live forensics. If we do post mortem forensics there is a 50% chance of finding useful info. If we do live forensics, there is an 80% chance of not triggering a boobytrap and if we don't trigger it there is a 100% chance of finding useful info on RAM and a 50% of finding useful info on Hard Drive. So which is best, based on Maximal Utility Principle, post mortem or live forensics?

Comment: Usually for Maximal Utility problems, you can use the concept of Expected Value. It's hard to say whether we can use the same thing here, because we don't know if one type of info is more valuable than another. Do note that with this case, we have a 50% chance of finding useful info on Post-mortem Forensics if we choose A, and if we choose B, we have an 80% chance to find info on RAM and a 40% chance to find info on HardDrive. If useful info isn't valued differently based on subject, I'd say you should go with B here.

Comment: This is what would make sense to me as well, but in the exam we were asked to use the Maximal Utility principle and I was at a loss as to how to calculate the Utility of each scenario. I determined actions to be {Postmortem, Live} and outcomes to be {success, failure} but couldn't figure out how to present utilities... Any idea on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76660/discussion-between-green-and-system).